# validation to ignore space at beginning of a text field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I try:

```
regno: {
           required: true,
           maxlength: 20,
           noSpace: true
       }
```

Can somebody assist me to validate text field that the beginning does not allow space?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to check leading white space with `pattern` from validation plugin additional method.

Example:

```js
$("#YourForm").validate({
  rules: {
    txtName: {
      pattern: /^(?!\s)/
    },
  },
  messages: {
    txtName: {
      pattern: 'No white space at begining.'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form id="YourForm" method="get" action="">
  <label>Textbox</label>
  <input id="txtName" name="txtName" type="text"/>
</form>
```

**Note: Don't forget to add `additional-methods.js` after `validate.js`**